# Check every values include or not in array using javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have the below type of 2 arrays. I want to check every value of `ValuesToBeCheckArr` should be in the ActualArr. If some values missing in the `actualarr` then it should be return 0 or false. Also, I have one operator variable, possible value of it `AND/OR`. I write the solution for `OR` operator **but not getting an idea for AND operator**

```
ActualArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,21,25,35,50,132];
ValuesToBeCheckArr = [2,3,50,132];
Operator = AND/OR

if(Operator == AND) {
   //check every value of ValuesToBeCheckArr should be in the ActualArr
} else if(Operator == OR) {
   //check at least one value of ValuesToBeCheckArr should be in the ActualArr
   const checkIncluded = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.some(item => arr2.includes(item));
   const isIncluded1 = checkIncluded(["1", "2"], ["3"]) // true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Operator == AND**

*==>* using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) combined with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like below

```js
const ActualArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,21,25,35,50,132];
const ValuesToBeCheckArr = [2,3,50,132];

const result = ValuesToBeCheckArr.every(v => ActualArr.some(a => v == a))
console.log(result);
```

---

> The `every()` method tests **whether all elements in the array pass the
> test implemented by the provided function**. It returns a Boolean value.

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array
> passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true
> if, in the array, **it finds an element for which the provided function
> returns true; otherwise it returns false**. It doesn't modify the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `.some` to `.every`. It will check if every item in the array satisfies the condition:

```
ActualArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,21,25,35,50,132];
ValuesToBeCheckArr = [2,3,50,132];
Operator = AND/OR

if(Operator == AND) {
   //check every value of ValuesToBeCheckArr should be in the ActualArr
   const checkIncluded = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.every(item => arr2.includes(item));
   const isIncluded1 = checkIncluded(ValuesToBeCheckArr, ActualArr)
} else if(Operator == OR) {
   //check at least one value of ValuesToBeCheckArr should be in the ActualArr
   const checkIncluded = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.some(item => arr2.includes(item));
   const isIncluded1 = checkIncluded(["1", "2"], ["3"]) // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation will work :-

```js
function checkInclusion(actualArr,checkArr,operator){
 let isIncluded = operator === "AND"?
 actualArr.every(item=>checkArr.includes(item)):
 actualArr.some(item=>checkArr.includes(item))
 return isIncluded;
}


console.log(checkInclusion(["1", "2","3"], ["1","3"],"AND"));
console.log(checkInclusion(["1", "2","3"], ["1","3"],"OR"));
```